# Installing browser extensions through the Windows registry, lost after opening the browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to install the Chome extension by writing to the Windows registry, and create Extension key in the path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions.Strangely, when the browser version is updated and browsing is opened again, the extension is lost, and the registry records are also lost.
I have tried installing the extension manually and this issue will not occur